# Why can I not access any documentation on Spring's website, its all blank

Tags: spring, spring-boot, documentation

When I try to access any of the documentation on springs website for Reference docs or API all the index pages come up blank.  I have tried in 3 browsers.

Even when I try on my phone though LTE it wont load.

http://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/htmlsingle/

http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/

Comment: There's an outage in the data centre that hosts the documentation. You can follow [@springops](http://twitter.com/springops) on Twitter for updates.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Now its back up and running

http://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/htmlsingle/

http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/

Here is the tweet from @springops

> http://docs.spring.io  is back and fully intact. Sorry for the delay
>   and thanks for your patience.

Comment: Thanks it was driving me nuts!   It was there for a day and they not working for a few days.